# MySQL on SELECT table, UPDATE views field

Tags: mysql

I have a `products` table with a `views` field. Every time I select a `product` I would like to increase `views`. With two query is simple:

```
-- Get the product 
SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = 1;

-- Increment the product's views
UPDATE product SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

I can do it in one query, without `triggers` or `stored procedures`?

Comment: I don't think you can do this without triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: Both queries are different and used for entirely different purposes.

Comment: Is there a reason you wanted an answer without triggers or a stored procedure? Or was it just purely curiosity?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ  just purely curiosity